# MVC razor view - Stop c# code compilation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a razor view showing details of a Hotel.

model for the view:

```
@model MySite.MyViewModels.Hotel
```

Have to show many details segments of the hotel. So, I have to check null for the Model on each segment. Is it possible if I can check once for all and stop the compilation of c# code if it is null.

You can say on top of the view If I can write something like:

```
@If(Model==null || Model.RoomsAvailable.Count<1)
{
//Don't read c# code on rest of the view now
}
```

Hope it make sense.

Comment: Do you want the code not to run if at least 1 segment is null?

Comment: Don't you want to check this on Controller and return empty View if you don't want render Complex View?

Comment: You can say that. But, the end requirement is to stop running c# code.

Comment: I gess the approach with check on Contoller allow you to do it.

Comment: @teovankot Any way to do it as I wanted? I mean if I can do it on view!

Comment: Maby i don't understand something, but you already write a way how you can do it on your View. What's problem with it?

Comment: @RashidAli - how do you suppose to stop compiling C# code? It is not dynamically compiled language, it is either full compilation or no compilation at all.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
pubilc ActionResult YourAction()
{
   if (null == YourModel)
   {
      return View(SomeEmptyView); // or return null
   }
   return View(Some legitimate view);
}
```

By that, you don't need to add logic to your view and you get what you wanted.